# typescript template literal in interface key error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Typescript v4.4.3

## [Reproducible Playground Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBED2CCuBbCcZAbwChlkQ4CAuZAZzClAHMBuc5AbTgBNeIvAPp0ABnwHCAJMUbMQLAL6iAunRD4ARtC4rkAH2Q4QAmKEEdFpUgkwhGySAgAWARmQBeEpwo4cwXjoAcgB2AAZNACYANkiQgFYAWniwgE5oxIAWCEzNRNTeFMSAZgR0+LKIFJDioIAaUkUOW3swZF5sOgxsfEI2rzIKKlpkACJRhooucX5BIRknNwA6PwDlNW5XVPCw112VBqbrGzsHDoRIrqxcAiIBzmGIOnHJ7hnJIThNBFU6LldIsVMvEVI0gA)

--

```js
interface IDocument {
  [added_: `added_${string}`]: number[] | undefined;
}
```

```js
const id = 'id';
const document: IDocument = {
  [`added_${id}`]: [1970]
}
```

What i've tried:

- I've confirmed that `id` in my code is a `string`.
- This happens when running `tsc` not just in VSCode warnings

```
[`added_abc`]: [1] // no error
[`added_${'abc'}`]: [1] // errors
[`added_${stringVariable}`] // errors
```

Is there some restrictions of using template literals or anything else I can investigate to diagnose this?

```
'string' and '`added_${string}`' index signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'string | string[] | number[]' is not assignable to type 'number[] | undefined'.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number[] | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

[image]

Comment: `Type 'string | string[] | number[]' is not assignable to type 'number[] | undefined'` indicates to me that it's the value it's having trouble with. It looks like it thinks the year is a string.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: @Aaron the issue seems to lie with the key (`added_${tech1.uuid}`) not the value. If i replace it with `added_abc` the error goes away. If i replace with `added_${'abc'}` the error returns

Comment: what kind of project is this? It is a react/angular app with typescript?

Comment: I figured out a reproducible example and updated the post

Comment: Please edit the code of the playground example into the question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that computed keys of types that are not single [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html) are widened to `string`, and such object literals that use them will end up being given a full string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) instead of anything narrower.  So something like `{[k]: 123}` will be given a narrow key if `k` is of type `"foo"` (`{foo: number}`), but if `k` is of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type `"foo" | "bar"` or a pattern template literal type (as implemented in [ms/TS#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598)) like `` `foo${string}` ``, then it will get a full string index signature (`{[x: string]: number}`).

There is an open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) asking for something better here; it's been around a long time and originally was asking only about unions of literals.  Now that pattern template literals exist this behavior is even more noticeable.  For now there is no built-in support in the language to deal with this.

---

In your code, `tech1.uuid` is of type `string`... not a string literal type, because the compiler infers string property types as `string` and not more narrowly.  If you want a narrower literal type there, you might want to give `tech`'s initializer a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const tech1 = {
  uuid: '70b26275-5096-4e4b-9d50-3c965c9e5073',
} as const;
/* const tech1: {
  readonly uuid: "70b26275-5096-4e4b-9d50-3c965c9e5073";
} */
```

Then to get the computed key to be a single literal, you will need another `const` assertion to tell the compiler that is should actually process the template literal *value* `` `added_${tech1.uuid}` `` as a template literal *type*:

```
const doc: IDocument = {
  name: "",
  [`added_${tech1.uuid}` as const]: [19700101], // <-- const assert in there
}; // okay
```

(They almost made such things happen automatically without a `const` assertion, but it broke too much code and was reverted in [microsoft/TypeScript#42588](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42588)).

---

If you need `tech1.uuid` to remain `string` and want more strongly-typed computed keys, then you will need to work around it with a helper function.  Here's one which takes a key of type `K` and a value pf type `V` and returns an object whose type is a type whose keys are in `K` and whose values are in `V`.  (It distributes over unions, since `kv(Math.random()<0.5 ? "a" : "b", 123)` should have type `{a: number} | {b: number}` and not `{a: number, b: number}`:

```
function kv<K extends PropertyKey, V>(k: K, v: V): 
  { [P in K]: { [Q in P]: V } }[K] {
  return { [k]: v } as any;
}
```

You can see that it behaves as desired with a pattern template literal key:

```
const test = kv(`added_${tech1.uuid}` as const, [19700101]);
/* const test: { [x: `added_${string}`]: number[]; } */
```

And so you can use it along with [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to build the object you want as an `IDocument`:

```
const doc: IDocument = Object.assign(
  { name: "" },
  kv(`added_${tech1.uuid}` as const, [19700101])
)
```

(Note that while you should be able to write `` {name: "", ...kv(`added_${tech1.uuid}` as const, [19700101])} ``, this isn't really working safely because the index signature is removed.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#42021](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42021) for more information.)

---

This may or may not be worth it to you; probably you can just write a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and move on:

```
const doc = {
  name: "",
  [`added_${tech1.uuid}`]: [19700101],
} as IDocument;
```

This is less safe than the prior solutions but it's very easy.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAhAhAKAzjATgLmR1zggHMBKZAb2GWSiR2QGsBTAT2QF5kADAA642IOAA8A+gBJqxAL59kAQywMmMANx1kAeh1qIzdh0KDhoyTOKkyC7Y0MxkCAEYArHjWQBtYwF1CAEYAJgBmZDltPQNmVzdCah8xQmtyAOQIMABbFzZcDQjkQF4NwCI9qP0AdyUIGDYAExinOISk0yERcWlZPBs5dMycvILIyOBgUlrcECUoNmQASQARBChsthqabQglLLYUnvItem8lOrr6iVNT87qu1Ns+fuzc3G8-ZAAfZEhz0Qh6rSjba7LACGZzADC6gAglgsHlag1aPZ1MhalAABaBTy0ej0MBgOB1QgAcgA7AAGFzBABswTJAFYALQMikAThpTIALGwuS4mWy6qymaEoByGWK2KyyaESQAabRyZSqBw4I66ABUjTRbExgQS2nowlOSAANlwCUTCAAiSnUumMlnszk8vkCoUUkVimkStlSiky63qpUanRjeiqpx1FaEJYrNYbXi4vHAvbIa3WhV4nx8a4XGTorEAOktdQUysa6W8gTZlIpgXrfizES0wCBOzYoPByAA0gA1AASbFNAjymwjqML2KThu+hOJyHJVNp9OZrI53N5-MFwtF4sl0tlzbkrfo4Gg8CQrAAbgAeHvINhiWoQOqqAAKuAQo9wMA4Pc4OVkD7AA+DAWEIHsgOvQg+woFpvHfZBSF7dJEm8ABFZCUHfdI+0KORvB7d5kyNNgYDAXAUHQlh0mvQoVGUCAOGDcNtWjKBgljZZVl2RNkAAeXcXUYCLFQsDgMgIAwWdElTG1rQiZt6BYa8MFzM582oKcS3nctGMjIDq1rCl60bChtAstsxlTLtZmQAAVDhR1heFf3qcdtSnHFZ1LUk7RXR11xdLd3V3b1fX9GV5UVU92JWHzs3k9NM1nbwNJuLodNLBQqxrOsG0CJtFQrONePWTQxjkIA)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assure TypeScript that `tech1.uuid` is a constant value.

```js
interface IDocument {
  name: string;
  [added_: `added_${string}`]: number[] | undefined;
}

const tech1 = {
  uuid: '70b26275-5096-4e4b-9d50-3c965c9e5073',
} as const;


const doc: IDocument = {
  name: "",
  [`added_${ tech1.uuid }` as const]: [19700101],
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBED2CCuBbCcZAbwChlkQ4CAuZAZzClAHMBuc5AbTgBNeIvAPp0ABnwHCAJMUbMQLAL6iAunRD4ARtC4rkAH2Q4QAmKEEdFpUgkwhGySAgAWARmQBeEpxw5gvOgByAHYABk0AJgA2COCAVgBaONCATiiEgBYIDM0ElN5khIBmBDS40ohk4KLAgBpSRWQ4emRbezAOazaHXmw6DGx8QjBPbwoqWmQAIin6ii5xfkEhGUcIF1cAOl9-ZGUmlu6wNW5XFLDQ10uVesUOIA)